# Replaceing multiple command calls

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Able to trim and transpose the below data with sed, but it takes considerable time. Hope it would be better with AWK. Welcome any suggestions on this

Input Sample Data:

```
[INX_8_60L          ] :9:Y
[INX_8_60L          ] :9:N
[INX_8_60L          ] :9:Y
[INX_8_60Z          ] :9:Y
[INX_8_60Z          ] :9:Y
```

Required Output:

```
INX?_8_60L¦INX?_8_60L¦INX?_8_60L¦INX?_8_60Z¦INX?_8_60Z
```

Comment: `sed -E 's/^\[([^_]*)([^\t ]*).*/\1?\2/' file | awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS=\|`???

Comment: how about `sed -E 's/....(.{6}).*/INX?\1/' ip.txt | paste -sd'|'`

Comment: Note that `¦` is not `|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `awk`, e.g.

```
awk -v n=0 '{printf (n?"!%s":"%s", substr ($0,2,match($0,/[ \t]+/)-2)); n=1} END {print ""}' file
```

Which will be orders of magnitude faster. It just picks out the (e.g. `"INX_8_60L"`) substring using `substring` and `match`. `n` is simply used as a `false/true` (`0/1`) flag to prevent outputting a `"!"` before the first string.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file` you would get:

```
$ awk -v n=0 '{printf (n?"!%s":"%s", substr ($0,2,match($0,/[ \t]+/)-2)); n=1} END {print ""}' file
INX_8_60L!INX_8_60L!INX_8_60L!INX_8_60Z!INX_8_60Z
```

Which appears to be what you are after. (**Note:** I'm not sure what your separator character is, so just change above as needed) If not, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

---

**Edit Per-Changes**

Including the `'?'` isn't difficult, and I just copied the character, so you would now have:

```
awk -v n=0 '{s=substr($0,2,match($0,/[ \t]+/)-2); sub(/_/,"?_",s); printf n?"¦%s":"%s", s; n=1} 
END {print ""}' file
```

**Example Output**

```
INX?_8_60L¦INX?_8_60L¦INX?_8_60L¦INX?_8_60Z¦INX?_8_60Z
```

And to simplify, just operating on the first field as in @JamesBrown's answer, that would reduce to:

```
awk -v n=0 '{s=substr($1,2); sub(/_/,"?_",s); printf n?"¦%s":"%s", s; n=1} END {print ""}' file
```

Let me know if that needs more changes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209286/discussion-on-answer-by-david-c-rankin-should-the-performance-be-better-with-aw).

Comment: @SamuelLiew - thank you, but does this questioner have the rep to enter chat?

Comment: Yes, see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/209286/?tab=access

Answer (score 1):

Don't start so many sed commands, separate the sed operations with semicolon instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to process the data in a single job and avoid regex. Below reading with `substr()` static sized first block and insterting `?` while outputing.

```
$ awk '{
    b=b (b==""?"":";") substr($1,2,3) "?" substr($1,5)
}
END {
    print b
}' file
```

Output:

```
INX?_8_60L;INX?_8_60L;INX?_8_60L;INX?_8_60Z;INX?_8_60Z
```

If the fields are not that static in size:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS="[[_ ]"                                     # split field with regex
}
{
    printf "%s%s?_%s_%s",(i++?";":""), $2,$3,$4      # output semicolons and fields
}
END {
    print ""
}' file
```

Performance of solutions for 20 M records:

Former:

```
real    0m8.017s
user    0m7.856s
sys     0m0.160s
```

Latter:

```
real    0m24.731s
user    0m24.620s
sys     0m0.112s
```

Comment: Good form operating on the first field with the default `FS`, simplifies operating on the whole thing!

Comment: James not able to get desired output, the string INX should be with INX?. Please check the provided sample input and output data

Comment: Oh, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can be very fast when used gingerly, so for simplicity and speed you might wish to consider:

```
sed -e 's/ .*//' -e 's/\[INX/INX?/' | tr '\n' '|' | sed -e '$s/|$//'
```

The second call to sed is there to satisfy the requirement that there is no trailing `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F'[[ ]+' '
  {printf "%s%s",(o?"¦":""),gensub(/INX/,"INX?",1,$2);o=1}
  END{print ""}
' file
```

The field separator is set (with `-F` option) such that it matches the wanted parameter.

The main statement is to print the modified parameter with the `?` character.

The variable `o` allows to keep track of the delimeter `¦`.

Comment: Looking for a single line code solution Oliv, not sure why the provided one is not fetching me a output